# Enable Multilingual typing in ios10

Tags: ios, internationalization

Some days ago the "*Multilingual typing*" option (which enables to type in two languages at the same time without having to switch between keyboards) in my iPhone 5S (with iOS 10) **automatically** shut down.

I already downloaded multiple dictionaries and enabled the respective keybords under the `General` menu.

[image]
[image]

Does someone know how to enable it again?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Settings -> General -> Dictionary`.
2. Select the languages you wish to use with the QuickType keyboard (allow it time to download).
3. Return to the `General -> Keyboards`. Tap `Keyboards` again, then tap **Add New Keyboard** and select the languages you just downloaded.

Instructions are from [this site](http://www.cultofmac.com/441836/how-to-set-up-multilingual-typing-in-ios-10/) and they also have screenshots in case you need them.

Edit: [Apple's iOS10 features site](http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#quickType-keyboard-multilingual-typing) lists the languages that are supported.  If it's not in this list then it's not supported (yet).

Comment: Unfortunately, I already downloaded multiple dictionaries and already selected the respective keyboards, but the issue is still present.

Comment: So none of those languages work, including emoji?  If you haven't restarted your iPhone, do that.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a link to Apple's site with the supported languages.  Remove the unsupported Dictionaries and see if it works with the supported ones.

Comment: I have updated my post as well. As you see, all languages are supported. Anyway, prediction works for Emoji, but only for the current language. However, multilanguage was working fine till some days ago, when it immediately shut down automatically without any (apparent) reason.

Comment: It doesn't look like Italian-English or Spanish-English are supported.

Comment: But it correctly worked till some days ago (I found this feature really helpful, I used it a lot).

Comment: Then I recommend contacting Apple Support.